# Angularjs change display for selected index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code but I only want to change the display response on the front end, not any json or database entry like I see on most SO forums with a similar issue.

```
     <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="hour in workhours" ng-init="selectedIndex=$index">
            <td >{{hour}}:00 - {{hour+1}}:00</td>

            <td ng-class = "{ 'full'     : !entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour),
                              'selected' : renderGreen(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength)}" 
                ng-click = "checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)"
                ng-repeat= "entry in data.calendar">

                    <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)">
                        Available
                    </span>
                    <span ng-if="!entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)">
                        Full
                    </span>

                    <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour) && selectedIndex==selectedRow && $index==selectedColumn"> 
                        {{ data.response }}
                    </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**controller.js**

```
(function() {

"use strict";

angular
    .module("availability")
    .controller("availabilityController", function($scope, $http){
        $scope.data          = {};
        $scope.data.response = "Available";
        $scope.workhours     =  Array.from({length:9}).map((_, i)=> i + 9); // creating all possible working hours in a day (9-17)

        $http.get('../api/availability.json')
             .then( function(response){
                $scope.data.calendar = response.data;
        }); 

        function setBuffer(date){
            var today       = formatDateToString(new Date('2016-05-18T11:27:00'));
            var bufferTime  = 1;
            if(date == today){
                bufferTime  = 2;
            }
            return bufferTime;
        }    

        function formatDateToString(date){
            var dd             = (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate();
            var MM             = ((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1);
            var yyyy           = date.getFullYear();
            return (yyyy + "-" + MM + "-" + dd);
        }

        function getRowAndColumn(row, column){
            $scope.selectedRow    = row;
            $scope.selectedColumn = column;
        }

        $scope.renderGreen = function(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength){
            if( $index == $scope.selectedColumn 
                && selectedIndex >= $scope.selectedRow
                && selectedIndex <= ($scope.selectedRow + jobLength - 1) && $scope.data.response == "Available")    
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        /* ===========================
        Check Availabiliy function
        ============================== */
        $scope.checkSlotAvailability = function(time, jobLength, date, availability) {
            var date      = date.Date;
            var calendar  = availability.calendar;
            var response  = "UNAVAILABLE";
            var buffer    = setBuffer(date);
            var selectedIndex = time - 9;

            if( jobLength < 1 || jobLength > 5 ){
                alert("Please enter job length from 1 to 5");
                response = "Available";
            }else {
                for( var i = 0; i < calendar.length; i++ ){

                    getRowAndColumn(selectedIndex, i); // for green render

                    if( date == calendar[i].Date ){

                        if( time < 9 || time > 17 ){    // Can't book before 9am or after 5pm. Code should never reach here.
                            response = "Unavailable";
                            break;
                        }else { 
                            for( var j = 0; j < calendar[i].HoursAvailable.length; j++){

                                if( time == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j]){
                                    if( ( time == 9 || time == 17 ) && calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j]
                                        || time - buffer < 9
                                        || time == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j] 
                                        && time - buffer == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j - buffer] 
                                        && time + buffer == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j + buffer] ){

                                            for( var k = j; k < calendar[i].HoursAvailable.length; k++ ){

                                                if( time >= 13 && time == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k] && time + jobLength <= 18 
                                                    && time - buffer   == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k - buffer] //5pm

                                                    || (time + jobLength + (buffer - 1))   == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k + jobLength + (buffer - 1)] 
                                                    &&  time - buffer                      == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k - buffer] 

                                                    ||  (time + jobLength + (buffer - 1))  == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k + jobLength + (buffer - 1)] ){   //9am
                                                        response = "Available";
                                                        break;
                                                }
                                                else if( k == calendar[i].HoursAvailable.length - 1 ){
                                                    response = "Unavailable";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            break;
                                    }else{
                                        response = "Unavailable";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }   
                                else if( j == calendar[i].HoursAvailable.length - 1 ){  //no available slot
                                        response = "Full";
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }else if( i == calendar.length - 1 ){   //no available date
                        response = "Full";
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }
            alert(response);
            console.log(response);
            $scope.data.response = response;
            return response;
        };
    });
```

})();

`getRowAndColumn()` is called somewhere else in the `checkSlotAvailability()` call but its job is to simply manipulate `checkSlotAvailability()`'s arguments to extract the row and column of the clicked cell.

As you see in the snap-shot below, the response comes through as I wanted with the targeted (clicked) cell, but I'm failing to get rid of the initial 'Available'. I understand how it's there but have tried everything no 200 OK for me yet. It still lingers around. I believe I might be missing some simple control logic somewhere in the html. Any help is welcome.

[image]

Shout out if you need me to show more code but I think it's just a simple fix from the code I've provided. The `entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)` checks the json for the hours available and html displays "Full" if that hour is not there otherwise "Available".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix was simple actually. Just added `&& !(selectedIndex==selectedRow && $index==selectedColumn)` logic to the **Available** span in html..

Answer (score 0):

This would be because the digest cycle isn't being triggered. You can force-trigger it by executing `$scope.$apply()` in the callback/promise that sets the `$scope.data.response` value.

Comment: thanks for responding. quite new to angularjs and never used the `$apply` directive yet. do you mind pointing me to the place to trigger? I've added the whole controller.

Comment: It looks like `$scope.data.response` is assigned the "Unavailable" value initially, and then mutated inside `checkSlotAvailability`. So putting `$scope.$apply()` right after mutation should do the trick (right above the `return` statement).

Comment: `angular.js:14525 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress` is the error in the console. No change on the display. Same result.